# Is it possible to serialize the iPod Media Library Metadata?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I'd like to extract the metadata of the iPod Library into a file.

Currently, I do this by creating a blank MPMediaQuery object that returns the entire library (As a MPMediaItemCollection), then loop through it and generate a datatable (im using monotouch) and serialize that.

This works, but its a bit slow for large libraries. Is there a cleaner approach to extracting all the library metadata? (a list of all songs, with artists, albums genres etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, there isn't a way of doing this directly. Only creating my own model of it, and serialising that.